# Identify this DC character

Tags: dc, character-identification

Can anyone tell me who the guy with the yellow and black mask is?

He's in the top right corner. Directly above Batgirl and to the right of Superman.

[image]

Image source - **[Harley's Joker](https://www.facebook.com/HarleysJoker/)**

Comment: What is the image from (why is there a live-action version next to a drawn version)?

Comment: @RedCaio The internet. I don't know (and its called cosplay, not live action).

Comment: lol, I know what cosplay is. Cosplay doesn't _usually_ include furniture and things hanging on walls so I thought this _might_ be from a movie or tv show. I guess I'll just do a reverse image search.

Comment: @RedCaio ... alot more background info is added to the answer below that gives the information you were seeking

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[image: Bolland artwork]

The original "**Joker Trophy Wall**" artwork is from "legendary" comic artist [Brian Bolland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Bolland) drawn in 2005 under commission.  A gallery posting about the origins and content of the original artwork is found [here](http://www.comicartfans.com/gallerypiece.asp?piece=124412). The artwork is not based upon any story in the DC canon.

[image: Misiano image]

The cosplay image was created in 2015 by photographer and cosplayer Anthony Misiano as a homage to the original artwork, and of course for the sake of his own publicity and sales.  A few articles about the cosplay image can be found [here](http://robot6.comicbookresources.com/2015/04/brian-bollands-joker-trophy-wall-brought-to-unsettling-life/) and [here](http://io9.com/cosplayer-brings-jokers-trophy-wall-to-life-as-a-creepy-1695474530).

To answer the question itself, according to the *description section* in the [artwork posting](http://www.comicartfans.com/gallerypiece.asp?piece=124412), the unknown "trophy" character is ["**Animal Man**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Man). And interestingly Brian Bolland created the cover art for the 1998 revival "Animal Man #1" (and is likely the reason that Bolland chose to include him in the 2005 Joker Trophy Wall artwork).  For reference, in the below comic cover, note Animal Man's triangular goggles in the mask, and blond hair with stringy bangs on his forehead.

[image: Animal Man comic cover]